# Change frame url in popover JavaScript

Tags: javascript, input, hidden, popover, src

It is necessary that when you click on the link, transmitted ip, which is' hidden input "in the popover and becomes part of the link. For example if you click the first link , the iframe src must be equal `"http://ip-score.com/checkip/94.45.43.42"`
If the second - `"http://ip-score.com/checkip/83.218.164.204"`
I try, but src not changing... [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkumqbym/9/)

```
 <a role='button' id='pop'  data-toggle='popover' >                  
       Check
       <input id='ip_id' type='hidden' value='94.45.43.42'> 
 </a>            
 <a role='button' id='pop'  data-toggle='popover' >              
       Check
       <input id='ip_id' type='hidden' value='83.218.164.204'> 
 </a>           
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
            content: function () {
                var ip;
                return ip= $(this).children("#ip_id").val();
                frame.src = 'http://ip-score.com/checkip/'+ip;
            },
            template:
                '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"> \
                <div class="arrow"></div> \
                <h3 class="popover-title"></h3> \
                <div> \
                    <span class="popover-content" id="ip_view"></span> \
                <div id="myPopoverContent">\
                <div id="outerdiv"> \
                    <iframe src="http://ip-score.com/checkip/94.45.43.42" id="innerIframe" scrolling="no"></iframe> \
                </div> \
                </div> \
                </div> \
            </div>',

            placement: 'bottom'
        });
        });
</script>
```